# Old .iso game says "This app can't run on your PC" when i try to run the SETUP.EXE - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, iso-image

I'm trying to run a childhood game i used to play all the time. I found an .iso file to the game and i have gotten it mounted as a drive and when i click the "SETUP.EXE" file it says "This app can't run on your PC - To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher"

Is there anyway to fix this problem or do i have to get a physical copy? I'm on a Windows 10 64bit system.

Comment: Telling us WHAT GAME might help.. But I have many games that I simply can't get to work outside of a VM anymore.  I doubt very seriously that having a physical ISO is your problem.  Your old game probably can't tell the difference.  Have you played with the comparability settings for the setup.exe itself?  Oh.. and for me?  [Pitfall, the mayan adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitfall:_The_Mayan_Adventure) is a good example. :)

Comment: A lot of older 32 bit games had 16 bit installers. While Windows emulates a few 16 bit installers it doesn't do many. 16 bit programs can't run on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131031-00/?p=2783 Explains that 64 bit Windows can only do *Acme* (an MS product) and InstallShield 16 bit installers.

Answer (score 0):

---

*Please note that while the guidelines below may (potentially) come off as somewhat overwhelming, running old games, in fact, often isn't very difficult.*

---

> Do I have to get a physical copy?

As pointed out in the comments, the error you are receiving is likely unrelated to (not) having a physical copy. And while there can be issues with game ISOs vs. "real" disks and copy protection, this doesn't really sound like what you're encountering.

> Is there anyway to fix this problem?

For programs (e.g. games) that are old enough that they can't run under Windows 10, typically some sort of [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) is required to use them. Old games can be roughly divided into two groups — games that require DOS to run and games that require e.g. Windows XP to run:

- For games designed to run under DOS, you can use [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/). It is self-contained and should include everything required to run the game.
- For games designed to run under e.g. Windows XP, you can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). Unfortunately, this is not a complete solution by itself (see *VirtualBox Caveats* below).

In either case, you would install the given virtual machine software, any additional required software (VirtualBox), and finally the game into the virtual machine. The game would then be run via this virtual machine, instead of Windows 10.

**VirtualBox Caveats**

- VirtualBox does not come with an OS (e.g. Windows XP). So after installing VirtualBox, you would need to grab an an appropriate ISO of Windows to install into it before attempting to install your game.
- VirtualBox has "guest additions" available for download from its website that you may want to install as well.
- Activation of the OS might be a consideration, though VirtualBox can take snapshots of a machine in a given state.
- Virtualization with e.g. VirtualBox has become slightly more complicated recently. That is, Windows 10 and many modern systems support [HyperV](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/), which is a technology used in conjunction with virtualizing operating systems. Basically, if you do need to run e.g. Windows XP, you may need to take extra steps to ensure VirtualBox and HyperV work/play nicely.
- As of VirtualBox 6.1, the host CPU *must* support hardware acceleration for virtualization. This can no long be disabled under *System → Acceleration* settings for the virtual machine.
- If your CPU doesn't support hardware virtualization, you can use [an old build of VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds) instead. For 64-bit systems, you'll probably want to use [VirtualBox 6.0.24](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_6_0). For 32-bit systems, you'll probably want to use [VirtualBox 5.2.44](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_2).
- While I refer to using e.g. Windows XP for a VirtualBox OS, you may be able to use any Windows version that supports your game. However, be aware that this can potentially have an impact on the overall performance of the virtual machine and your system (i.e. later Windows versions require more resources, so it's often better to use the earliest version supported by the game).

**General Notes**

- DOSBox and VirtualBox are not interchangeable. However, *some* old games may have support for both DOS and Windows. But this depends entirely on the game itself.
- Both DOSBox and VirtualBox likely require at least some minor additional configuration to get them working as you desire, independent of any game installation.
- Older games may need other "fixes" to run on modern hardware (i.e. at particular resolutions), independent of any virtualization.